# Smallest prime $p$ such that $2\mid\operatorname{ord}_p(q)$, the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

$\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$Let $q$ be prime. I want to upper bound the smallest odd prime $p$ such that $2\mid\ord_p(q)$ (where $\ord_p(q)$ is the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $p$).

Using the fact that the smallest quadratic nonresidue in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ is less than $q^{1/4+\varepsilon}$, we can get that such a $p$ is less than $q^{1/4+\varepsilon}$ via quadratic reciprocity. However, this $p$ satisfies the *a priori* much stronger condition that

$$q^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1\bmod p.$$

Whereas this problem simply asks for the first $p$ such that

$$q^{\frac{p-1}{2^{y}}}\equiv -1\bmod p,$$

where $y$ is *some* multiplicity of factors of $2$ dividing $p-1$.

So the question naturally becomes, **can we find an upper bound less than $q^{1/4+\varepsilon}$** (edit: $q^{1/(4\sqrt{e})+\varepsilon}$, see edit below)? This isn't as elementary as one expects.

*Attempts/Heuristics:*

---

Consider the (Eisenstein) polynomial $x^{2^n}-q$ for some (large) $n$ and the corresponding Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{2^n},q^{1/{2^n}}]/\mathbb{Q}$. Then we may try to upper bound the smallest norm of primes in certain conjugacy classes. For example, unramified split primes $\mathfrak{p}$ correspond to $2^n\mid N_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{p})-1$ and

$$q^{\frac{N_\mathbb{Q}(\mathfrak{p})-1}{2^n}}\equiv 1\bmod{N_\mathbb{Q}(\mathfrak{p})}.$$

However, the unconditional upper bounds we arrive at here are even worse, depending on a power of the discriminant of the field extension (which is larger than $q$).

---

Besides noting that under the GRH, we can easily find a bound logarithmic in $q$ (using Chebotarev or simply reciprocity), we can also consider [Linnik's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem). Namely, considering for example primes $s\equiv 1\bmod{2^n}$, where $2^n\approx \log(q)$, it proves the existence of such a prime $s<\log^5(q)$ (approximately). Noting that there are precisely

$$N=\dfrac{\lvert\mathbb{Z}/s\mathbb{Z}\rvert}{\gcd{(2^n,\lvert\mathbb{Z}/s\mathbb{Z}\rvert})}=\dfrac{s-1}{2^n}<\dfrac{\log^5(q)}{\log(q)}$$

distinct $2^n$-th powers modulo $s$, there is *a priori* a $\frac{\log(q)-1}{log(q)}$ chance that $2\mid\ord_s(q)$. Considering other powers $2^k$, and being guided by GRH, it seems that a logarithmic bound in $q$ should be possible.

---

Edit: As GH from MO [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403147/smallest-prime-p-such-that-2-mid-operatornameord-pq-the-multiplicative#comment1032256_403147) below, we can find a quadratic nonresidue less than $q^{1/(4\sqrt{e})+\varepsilon}$, which provides a slightly better bound for the a priori stronger case.

Minor Edit: Another cute way of thinking about this is with this equivalent question:

*What is the smallest odd prime factor in the sequence $q^1+1,q^2+1,q^3+1,q^4+1,...$?*

Comment: In fact the least quadratic nonresidue modulo $q$ is $\ll_\varepsilon q^{1/(4\sqrt{e})+\varepsilon}$, as follows from Burgess's bound and Vinogradov's trick. See the remarks after Theorem 9.27 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I.

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t trying hard to be precise with that bound as I was using it to illustrate why the bound should be lower.

Comment: I doubt one can do much better unconditionally than the state of the art for the least quadratic nonresidue here.  Note for instance that for primes $p = 3 \hbox{ mod } 4$ - half of the primes - your condition is precisely equivalent to being a quadratic non-residue.